# Can you help our Puzzle Heroe's with their amnesia?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> **DISASTER HAS STRUCK!!!**

[image: Amnesia]

Our Stack O' Puzzle Heroe's have amnesia! It happened last night, when each one of the puzzle heroes' arch-nemesis defeated them all by giving them all AMNESIA! They all lost their brilliant puzzle solving skills.

The heroes cannot remember anything, including who they are!  In a rare showing of compassion, each of their enemies has given them a chance to regain their memory, along with their brilliant puzzle solving skills.

Each hero is to meet their arch-nemesis at a certain place, on a certain day, at a specific time. The puzzle world is in total chaos until this information can be deciphered. They need you.

Here are the only clues the villains have left for us:

**Clue 1:** JOHNMARK who doesn't live in a warm climate, is supposed to meet 8 hours and 15 minutes after one of the other heroes.

**Clue 2:** Both PIRATE and RAND Al THOR are meeting in Florida but neither meeting in the southern most city and neither are supposed to meet at the earliest times the villains specified.

**Clue 3** The California meeting is at 2:45pm

**Clue 4** RAND Al THOR isn't meeting at 2:45pm

**Clue 5** RAND Al THOR isn't meeting on THU

**Clue 6** The MON meeting time is 14.5 hours after the WED meeting

[image: Puzzle Data]

[image]

Comment: Better them than me. Anyway I don't look good in a cape.

Comment: LOL - If you solve, you will be featured in  my next one! :p

Comment: is "heroe's" intentional? or is it supposed to be "heroes"

Comment: Rule 2 seems to imply that multiple people can meet in the same city, is that correct? (i.e. it says that two people must both meet in the northern-most of two cities in Miami)

Comment: In fact there seems to be multiple contradictions, assuming unique people/cities/times/days... Clue 1 places John @ 11pm (only time 8h15m after another time, unless there's timezone trickery going on), but then clues 2+4 force Rand into 11pm too

Comment: If anyone would like the solution messaged to them, let me know.

Comment: @JohnS. - don't need the solution, but can you clarify my comments above?

Comment: It took me this long to realize St. Pete is in Florida not Russia :-)

Comment: @Alconja, I just re-checked, and all the clues only point to one solution. No two people share anything. It's very straight forward, no trickery.

Comment: @JohnS. Fair enough, my logic (or math/geography) must just be failing me. I don't see how Pirate & Rand can both meet in Florida (Miami or St. Pete), but neither in Miami (southern most). Surely that makes them both St. Pete... Similarly, clue 2 tells us that Pirate & Rand must be meeting at 2:45pm & 11pm (not the earliest times, unless you meant "earliest time", not "time**s**"), which means no one else can, but clue 1 means John has 11pm (only other gap with a 15min included is 8:30a-2:45p = 6h15m)... I guess I'll just leave it to someone else.

Comment: Are you sure you mean neither PIRATE nor RAND Al THOR is meeting at 8:30 am by "neither are supposed to meet at the earliest times the villains specified"?

Comment: @JohnS. I read the sixth clue and thought....wait a minute, how is a Monday time 14.5 hours after a Wednesday? ;) I know what you mean, but for a second there... **Also** are time zones important at all?

Comment: @Brandon_J - so what that means is, Mondays time should be 14.5 hours after the time set for Wednesday. Whatever time Wednesday is, Monday will be 14.5 hours after.

Comment: @Nautilus , yes neither Pirate nor RAND should meet at 8:30 ( the earliest time )

Comment: So, to be clear: are all times, places, dates, and people used _exactly once_ **or** is there some flexibility? @JohnS.

Comment: @Brandon_J , yep all are used only one time, with none left over.

Comment: So how does JohnMark meet 8hrs & 15 mins after another hero on a different day? None of the time pairs work. @JohnS.

Comment: @Brandon_J : https://www.jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/index.php?language=en#(at:s,items:!(!(Boston,'Los%20Angeles',Miami,'St.%20Petersburg'),!(AeJey,Pirate,JonMarkPerry,'Rand%20al!'Thor'),!('8:30AM','10:00AM','2:45PM','11:00PM'),!(Monday,Wednesday,Thursday,Saturday)),ms:t,n:!(),nc:4,ni:4,p:!(),v:0)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer (and perhaps to some of the still seemingly unaddressed concerns noted in the comments) to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go with

> John Mark: Boston, Monday 2300
>  Aejay: Miami, Wednesday 0800
>  Pirate: Los Angeles, Thursday 1445
>  Randal: St. Petersburg, Saturday 1000

You can check this fits all the clues

> Except clue 2, where @Alconja has pointed out a couple of problems: "I don't see how Pirate & Rand can both meet in Florida (Miami or St. Pete), but neither in Miami (southern most). Surely that makes them both St. Pete..."
>  Now, if you look at clue 4, it appears to be redundant: clue 2 says Randal is in Florida, clue 3 says the California meeting is at 1445. Then clue 4 says that Randal is not meeting at 1445, which would follow from the previous two, since California is not Florida. Right? Unless...
>  **California has been annexed by Florida**. Now the contradiction in clue 2 is resolved and clue 4 is not vacuous.
>  No doubt the villains are behind this annexation. But they'll never get away with it!!